# SUM a group of SUMS

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I am having trouble creating a SUM of two lines in my code that already have SUMS.  I end up with an error.  Can someone help me with the code? The calculation that I want is SUM(yr_L / yr_CC). I realize I can't use alias's to do calculations, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Below works, without the complex SUM calculation lines ...

```
SELECT
IF (Artist LIKE '%Bethel%' , 'Bethel', NULL ) as Artist,
COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) as "c_CC",
ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_CC,
COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_L,
ROUND(SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_L,
COUNT(IF(FD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_F,
ROUND(SUM(F28) / COUNT(IF(FD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_F,
COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_MT,
ROUND(SUM(MT28) / COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_MT,
ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
    ROUND(SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
    ROUND(SUM(MT28) / COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
    ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0)
    AS yr_Total
FROM praisecharts_reporting.large_sales_report
GROUP BY 1
```

Here is what I did that creates an error (the equation I added has spaces around it):

```
SELECT
IF (Artist LIKE '%Bethel%' , 'Bethel', NULL ) as Artist,
COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) as "c_CC",
ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_CC,
COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_L,
ROUND(SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_L,

SUM (
        (
            SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) -- yr_L
        ) / 
        (
            SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) -- yr_CC
        )
    )
    AS r_L_C,

COUNT(IF(FD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_F,
ROUND(SUM(F28) / COUNT(IF(FD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_F,
COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_MT,
ROUND(SUM(MT28) / COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_MT,
ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
    ROUND(SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
    ROUND(SUM(MT28) / COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
    ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0)
    AS yr_Total
FROM praisecharts_reporting.large_sales_report
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: MySQL is the DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is probably to just repeat the two sums to take the quotient:

```
SELECT
    IF (Artist LIKE '%Bethel%' , 'Bethel', NULL) AS Artist,
    COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) AS "c_CC",
    ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13, 0) AS yr_CC,
    COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_L,
    ROUND(SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_L,
    COUNT(IF(FD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_F,
    ROUND(SUM(F28) / COUNT(IF(FD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_F,
    COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) as c_MT,
    ROUND(SUM(MT28) / COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) as yr_MT,
    ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
        ROUND(SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
        ROUND(SUM(MT28) / COUNT(IF(MTD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) +
        ROUND(SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL)) * 13,0) AS yr_Total,
    -- new code here:
    ROUND( (SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL))) /
           (SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(CCD > 0,1,NULL))), 0) AS new_column
FROM praisecharts_reporting.large_sales_report
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: When I input that new code, I get this error ... `ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROUND( (SUM(L28) / COUNT(IF(LD > 0,1,NULL))) / (SUM(CC28) / COUNT(IF(' at line 14`

Comment: @RyanDahl Sorry, I was missing a comma right before `-- new code here`.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much. Amazing how one little comma can take the whole formula down!

Comment: Yes, it's because the parser doesn't know that it is a little mistake, so it reports something which seems larger than it is :-)